# get php info for apache 2

Tags: apache2, php

I want to see my php information on my apache2, how I can configure to see php info?
your help and information is great appreciated,

Comment: Are you talking about the default php webpage or the php errors from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a file, call it phpinfo.php or whatever you wish, and put this code in it

```
<? phpinfo(); ?>
```

See also http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php